# Como mostrar la opción de Eliminar en Toobal cuando se haga un click largo en un listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, toolbar

Tengo un ListView personalizado y funciona bien pero quiero agregar la opcion que cuando se haga un click largo sobre el elemento de la lista aparezca una opcion de eliminar o editar el elemento, como lo que hace whatsapp. tengo un toolbar pero no se si ese es que se usa ni como s hace.
este el el codigo del lonclick que tengo:

```
lvPesquisasSemana.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

AL hacer el longclic me muestra el toas con la posicion del elemento pero quiero que el usuario tenga varias opciones

Answer (score 1):

Buen día amigo te comparto la manera en la que yo realizo el menu de manera dinámica.

```
//Con esta variable mostrarías o ocultarías la opción de tu menu
public boolean isShowMenu = true;

//Creas tu toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


//Método en el cual actualizas las opciones de tu menu
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(isShowMenu);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

// Método donde creas tu menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}


//Cuando quieras ocultar o mostrar tu botón cambias el valor de la variable isShowMenu y mandas llamar este método para actualizar tu menu.
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Espero te sea de utilidad saludos